# What should be the code architecture to download and cache offline data (Images/Videos/3d Models) ?

Tags: c#, algorithm, design-patterns, architecture, software-design

I'm developing an application which has a 3D room. Each room is a 3d model and can contain media boards. each media board contains image(s) as slides or video. I have created following Data Models :

```
class Room {
 string id;
 string room3dmodellink;
 List<Mediaboards> mediaboards;
}

class Mediaboard{
 string id;
 string mediaboard3dModleLink;
 List<Slide> slides;
}

class Slide{
 string id;
 string imageLink;
}
```

These data models are populated from server. i need to know how to architect this code to download and cache all models and images in local storage and get/Load from cache on demand, Also should have mechanism to update cache/offline data. Where should i store path of the locally downloaded models and images ? Storing path of downloaded images/models in these models doesn't make sense to me. Need Suggestion/solution.
Thanks

P.S: I'm using Unity 3D and C#.

Answer (score 0):

Unity hides this kind of information in [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html).
This allows to keep things ok for all platforms.

You can also use [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html), which is available for all platforms too.
Inside of that, the storage mechanisms are yours.

To handle this cache, each object will need a unique id and you may check for versions (or any equivalent value), so that you know when the cached object needs to be updated.

The cache needs to include some kind of index table which will allow to retrieve the wanted element in the cache given its id. This table is part of the cache (so, it is inside [Application.persistentDataPath](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-persistentDataPath.html) too).

You may also want to delete oldest or rarely used elements. So your cache will need to store these information.